# Guacamole : Message will not be sent because the WebSocket session has been closed

Tags: windows, websocket, server, rdp, guacamole

I used Apache Guacamole to connect to a Windows Server 2022 by RDP from browser.

I encounter some times an issue with Apache Guacamole. The login failed and I had this message in the log file : Message will not be sent because the WebSocket session has been closed

I used Guacamole with docker. I followed this steps to install the images and configure them : https://guacamole.apache.org/doc/gug/guacamole-docker.html

The issue does not appear often, but from time to time.

Have you any idea how to fix it definitely?